# Where should I require files from another engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, require, rails-engines

I'm writing a Rails gem. Where should I `require` files from other engine? In my engine's main file or in each file that uses other gem's functions?

For example, I use `devise` only in `User` model (and in configuration file). Should I require it in `app/models/user.rb` file only? And what about `haml` gem that is used for rendering each page?

I saw `locomotive` and `forem` engines. First `require`s all other gems in its engine file. And the second `require 'kaminari'` in engine file and `require 'cancan'` in models.

What's right?

Comment: It's really up to you actually. I would say `devise` in the `lib/my_engine.rb` since you need it in various places. But I really don't think there is a standard de-facto way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, if your gem has dependencies, then it should require them in the gem's main file.  All the files are read when the gem is loaded, and once the require has been performed, it won't be performed again.  Requiring dependencies in the main file for the gem puts all of the requires in a central location, making maintenance easier.